# Nested component error: {#each} only iterates over array-like on drop

Tags: javascript, svelte-3, svelte-component

I'm  trying to create a component that uses nested drag and drop from [sevelte-dnd-action](https://github.com/isaacHagoel/svelte-dnd-action), using this object:

```
$forms = [
  {
    id: hexID(),
    title: 'Data - test',
    defined: true,
    components: [
      {
        id: hexID(),
        type: 'text',  
        size: 'long',
                    placeholder: 'None'
      },
      {
        id: hexID(),
        type: 'text',
        size: 'normal',
        placeholder: 'Test'
      },
      {
        id: hexID(),
        type: 'text',
        size: 'normal',
        placeholder: 'CCC'
      },
      {
        id: hexID(),
        type: 'text',
        size: 'normal',
        placeholder: 'CDS'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: hexID(),
    title: 'Emails',
    defined: true,
    components: [
      {
        id: hexID(),
        type: 'text',
                    size: 'normal',
        placeholder: 'RGzzzz'
      },
      {
        id: hexID(),
        type: 'select',
                    size: 'normal',
        placeholder: 'RGrrr'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: hexID(),
    title: 'Tel',
    defined: true,
    components: [
      {
        id: hexID(),
        type: 'text',
                    size: 'normal',
        placeholder: 'RaaaG'
      },
      {
        id: hexID(),
        type: 'select',
                    size: 'normal',
        placeholder: 'Rtrea'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I call it first at the app.svelte and pass the array inside the object to the Horizontal.svelte component:

```
<section class='create_form_body'
   use:dndzone={{items:$forms}}
   on:consider={handleDndConsider}
   on:finalize={handleDndFinalize}>
{#each $forms as form (form.id)}
  <HorizontalList {form}/>
{/each}
```

this is the Horizontal component:

```
<script>
 export let form
 function handleDndConsider(cid, e) {
    let chosenOne = $forms.findIndex(x => x.id === cid)
    $forms[chosenOne].components = e.detail.items;
    $forms = [...$forms]
 }
 
function handleDndFinalize(cid, e) {
    let idx = $forms.findIndex(x => x.id === cid)
    $forms[idx].components = e.detail.items;
    $forms = [...$forms]
}
</script>

<div class='form_box'>
<div class='form_header'>
 {form.title}
<div class='form_header_combo'>
  <span>title</span>
</div>
</div>
    <section class='input_list'
        use:dndzone={{items: form.components}}
        on:consider={(e) => handleDndConsider(form.id, e)}
        on:finalize={(e) => handleDndFinalize(form.id, e)}
    >           
        {#each form.components as component (component.id)}
                <ComponentGetter type={component}/>
        {/each}
    </section>
</div>
```

if i delete all thee DIVs and leave the section it works perfectly, but with the divs it gives `error:  {#each} only iterates over array-like objects.`Could someone give me a choice other  than deleting the divs?
this is the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/2357f46610da4363a80348852473a227?version=3.29.4)

Answer (score 1):

the cause of the problem was the absence of the key 'type' in the `use:dndzone={{items: objectArray, type: 'define name'}}`. here is the link to the corrected code [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/f3b2f1ed1c6847fd8d8dc19cbf098952?version=3.22.2)